# Why does char concatenation returns "int" sum?

Tags: java, string, char, sum

the question says it all, here is the code :

```
public class Chars
{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Chars c = new Chars();
        String res = c.test("abcd");
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    public String test(String str){
        String res = "";
        res += str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(2); 
        return res;
    }
}
```

This returns : "196" which is the sum of the ASCII value of `a` and `c` !
Why does this happen? , I would expect to get "ac".
If I modify the second line in the test() method like this :

```
res = res + str.charAt(0)+str.charAt(2);
```

The result is indeed "ac".
Please somebody help me with this doubt. I just can`t find and answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in the way the concatenations are constructed.

First: `res += str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(2);`

Here, the two `char` values are added together first.  Binary numeric promotion occurs ([JLS, Section 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)).

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

That means that the values are promoted to `int`, creating your `196`.  That is then added to `str`, appending `"196"`.

Second: `res = res + str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(2);`

Here, the `res + str.charAt(0)` is performed first, and a `String` plus a `char` appends the `char` (via [String Conversion, JLS 15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1), resulting in a new `String`.

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

Then, the second `char` is appended similarly.

If you were to say

```
res = res + (str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(2));
```

then the result would be the same (appending the `196`) as with `+=`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, a very good explanation. However, in the first case I use "+=" shouldn't that mean "res + str.charAt(0)..." I mean when does the addition of the current value of "res"  occurs ? I thought it was like adding first the actual value of "res"  and then add the other operands, but it seems to be the other way around.

Comment: That's because `+=` is of lower precedence then `+`, so the `+` occurs first.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, been programming for almost 2 years now, and still get confused or forget this little things :P

Comment: @FraK The JLS says "E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))" [`T` is the type of `E1` but it's not needed here].  Note that it puts parentheses around everything.  So `A += B` is equivalent to `A = (A) + (B)` rather than `A = A + B`.

Answer (score 1):

Chars are not strings. You would expect to get "ac" if "a" and "c" were Strings. Chars are unsigned integers which represent characters, and if you add any two chars, the result is converted to int. You have to cast using `(char)` if you want to treat as a char or assign it to a variable which is declared as `char`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `charAt()` returns char value, instead of String. Therefore `+` operator here doesn't stand for concatenation, but it's a simple addition of two numbers.

This works if both operands of `+` are a number. If one of them is s `String`, `+` does not peform addition anymore, but both operands are casts to `String` and concatenation is performed instead. Therefore if you include `res` into the mix, the result of

```
res + str.charAt(0)
```

will be a `String` and using the same logic, the whole thing

```
res += str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(2);
```

will also be evaluated to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

[**JLS §15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18) explains why:

> If only one operand expression is of type `String`, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

In your case, you are doing: `char + char`. Non of the operands is of type String, so the classical numerical addition is executed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to extract a character from a string and get a `String` of length 1, instead of a `char`, then instead of:

```
str.charAt(i)
```

you can do this:

```
str.substring(i, i+1)
```

or this:

```
Character.toString(str.charAt(i))
```

or:

```
("" + str.charAt(i))
```